# Disposition of duplicates identified in review queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, duplicate-questions, triage

I'm new to reviewing and have so far seen several questions that are complete and understandable enough to be clearly identified as duplicates of questions with an answer relevant to the new poster's problem.  I'm not sure which button to click for categorization because the question "looks ok" if not for the duplicate and I don't know if being a duplicate makes it "unsalvageable".  How is this supposed to be handled?  For now I am linking the existing question in comments and the skipping the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While normally I wouldn't have an issue with one using the "Skip" functionality...this is a case in which you know *exactly* what to do.  The "Unsalvageable" button is what will get you access to the dialog to close the question as a duplicate, and I humbly ask that you use it.

While I get the phrasing is a bit off-putting, "unsalvageable" can also mean that, from the perspective of a third-party editor, there's no way to make this question on-topic and not a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional context and letting me know that I would find the option to close as a duplicate behind that button.  It makes much more sense now and doesn't seem as extreme.